# Can we access default item files in Document Sets?

Tags: document-set, default-document

I understand that default items can be added to document sets through the Document Set Settings link.

Clearly, the files you upload are stored somewhere.

How can I access these files to keep them up to date without having to store a second copy in another library and remembering to re-upload them to the document set when I change these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the Document Set templates from Windows Explorer:

- From Internet Explorer (but not other browsers), visit a library in the Site Collection.
- Click the LIBRARY ribbon tab
- Click "Open with Windows Explorer"

You can now double-click the files to open, edit and save.

[image]

You may also be able to open Windows Explorer and right-click Network and click "Map network drive" to map a drive letter to a URL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are stored in the Content Types hidden folder (_cts) in the top level web of a Site Collection. You can see this from SharePoint Designer:

- Open the site
- in the Navigation panel click "All Files"
- click "_cts"
- click your Content Type

There you will find the Content Type's home page (docsethomepage.aspx) and your uploaded files.

Comment: Is it accessable from a browser?

Comment: Other than from the Content Type maintenance pages? (https://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_layouts/15/mngctype.aspx)

Comment: Yes, other than that. I'm looking for a way of directly accessing and editing the files.

Comment: The "_" folders are typically not directly accessible. So this will not work: http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_cts/testdocset/yourDocument.docx You can access the files from Windows Explorer. (maybe!)